# How to get my aloe to grow

Tags: growth, aloe

I was given this aloe pup as a gift some years ago and never got around to replanting it from its tiny pot. Since then it has never quite grown. Its 3 leaves are still green but it has stayed a tiny plant.

I was wondering what I could do to stimulate growth?

Some side info that might be useful.

When i first got it, I placed it in my south facing window but it burned terribly there so i moved it to the side, on my dresser where it got some sun and some shade. My apartment stays very warm and sunny thru the year.

When I first got it I also overwatered and almost killed the plant. Luckily i think i realized quickly enough what was happening and stopped watering it so frequently. Would this stunt its growth?

Is it sunlight? the soil? watering? the size of its pot?

Comment: Can we get a picture, please? This is a nice description, but seeing your plant would help you get better answers. Welcome to Gardening SE! After your [edit] with a picture, and while you wait for answers, please take the [tour] and browse our [help] to learn more about the site and the SE system in general.

Answer (score 3):

From what you've said, you seem to be saying your aloe is still in the original 'tiny' pot. Given you've had it some years, it must be desperately clinging on to life, but unable to grow any larger because it has no root room. A plant needs a good root system in order to support its topgrowth, so turn it out of its pot - if the rootball is solid with roots wrapped around, pot on into something only a size or two larger initially, using a commercial potting mix to which you've added some grit or perlite.